# Alternative description of generalized orthogonal group.

Tags: real-analysis, lie-groups, bilinear-form, linear-groups

I am studying Lie groups and Lie algebras.One of the standard examples of Lie groups is $O(n;k)$,which is called the generalized orthogonal group.It is defined by $O(n;k)=\{T\in GL_n(\mathbb C): [Tx,Ty]_{n,k}=[x,y]_{n,k}\}$ where $[.,.]$ is the bilinear form $[x,y]_{n,k}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_iy_i-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k x_{n+i}y_{n+i}$.I am trying to show the following:

$O(n;k)=\{A\in GL_{n+k}(\mathbb R):A^tgA=g\}$ where $g$ is the diagonal matrix with $1$ in the first $n$ diagonal entries and $-1$ in the last $k$ diagonal entries.

But I am unable to show this.I am sure that this equality is in the isomorphism sense.Can someone tell me a way how to proceed?

Is there any typo anywhere in the above?If yes,please correct.

Comment: It helps not to switch names in the middle.  $T$ and $A$ are the same matrix.  Also, you need to decide whether you want a matrix from $GL_{n+k}(\Bbb{R})$ which is the real Lie group or $GL_{n+k}(\Bbb{C})$ which is the complex Lie group.

Comment: @ChadK Actually this is from an assignment problem given by our professor and I think it was the typo that caused problem.We need to define $O(n;k)=\{A\in GL_{n+k}(\mathbb R): [Ax,Ay]=[x,y]\}$

Comment: Try writing down what $y^t g x$ evaluates to in coordinates.

Comment: @ChadK Yes,now I can do it very well,the typo was the source of problem.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a bit where you say what the typo is but I assume it is that it is supposed to say $-1$ (not $k$) for the last $k$ entries.

Comment: @Callum Yes,made the correction.